# Terraform doesn't build triton machine

Tags: terraform, triton

I've set my first steps into the world of terraform, I'm trying to deploy infrastructure on Joyent triton.

After setup, I wrote my first .tf (well, copied from the examples) and hit terraform apply. All seems to go well, it doesn't break on errors, but it doesn't actually provision my container ?? I doublechecked in the triton web gui and with "triton instance list". Nothing there.

Any ideas what's going on here ?

```
provider "triton" {  
  account = "tralala"  
  key_id  = "my-pub-key"  

  url = "https://eu-ams-1.api.joyentcloud.com"  

}  

resource "triton_machine" "test-smartos" {  
  name    = "test-smartos"  
  package = "g4-highcpu-128M"  
  image   = "842e6fa6-6e9b-11e5-8402-1b490459e334"  

  tags {  
    hello = "world"  
    role = "database"  
  }  

  cns {  
    services = ["web", "frontend"]  
  }  

}
```

Comment: It would help if you posted your code as an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Are you using a private Triton cloud or are you using Joyent's public Triton cloud? What region are you using/expecting to see things in?

Comment: I'm using Joyents public cloud.